# How to create copies of a directory with sequential numbers

Tags: bash, shell, directory, cp

I have a template directory containing sub-directories and MS-Windows links.
This directory needs to be sequentially reproduced at the same folder level.
The range needs to be from one to twenty.

So, how do you do that from the command line?

Comment: Does not sound too hard, what did you try? What went wrong? Can you use symbolic links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After scouring the net I fell across some bits and pieces that did some of the things I was looking for, however they needed to be put together in a another way to run correctly from the  command-line:

```
base=ny-redaktion
for ((start=4, count=2; $((count--)); $((start++)) ))
do 
  cp -ar  "$base" "$base$start"
done
```

This does exactly what I need, and if you wish to use it as a script it'll work as well, but you your have to always edit the base=***** script to what ever your original directory is called, and edit the start=*#* variable to the number of copies you need.

I hope this will be a help to anyone looking for a way to make sequential copies of a directory.